# How to make a list scrolling up using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

http://e-nutritionplanet.com.bd/school/

Just like the Notice Board Scrolling/animation in the above site.

I tried for these:

```
<ul id="scrollUp">
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right"></i> Md rezaul Karim Bangladesh</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right"></i> Md rezaul Karim Bangladesh</a></li>
            ...
</ul>
```

Comment: check [jQuery Scrollbox](http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Carousel-Marquee-Like-List-Scrolling-Plguin-For-jQuery-Scrollbox.html) and [jQuery Marquee](https://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee)

Comment: let me know if you want to use any jquery animation for the same, because this can be also possible using marquee tag of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try same thing using marquee tag from HTML if you dont wanna go for Jquery and that will load faster.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML marquee Tag</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <marquee direction="up" behavior=scroll scrollamount="1" onmouseleave="this.start();" onmouseover="this.stop();">

        This text will scroll from bottom to up
        <br/>
        This text will scroll from bottom to up
        <br/>
        This text will scroll from bottom to up
        <br/>
        This text will scroll from bottom to up
        <br/>

    </marquee>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The above code works ncely but there is a blank space at first for sometime then the element comes up.    I don't want the blank space first. How can i remove the blank space?????????

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i can solve the problem.

1. It conflicts with:
2. It also conflicts with:

Thanks to almighty and thanks to all.